# Highlighted words in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, modelica, dymola

I've been coding in Dymola for few months and I found it really useful that when I highlighted a word, all the identical words across the code got highlighted as well. The question is that now I'm still coding in Modelica, but using Eclipse 2021-09. Is there any similar tool or shorcut to make something similar? Or any advice to improve the user experience and make it easier to understand and move through models (apart from the so-called CTRL+F)?
Thanks in advance, I really appreciate any help you could provide.

Comment: In which editor? The _Generic Text Editor_ provides this feature: right-click and choose _Open With > Generic Text Editor_. Use Ctrl+K to jump to the next current selected word (Ctrl+Shift+K for previous word).

Comment: Nice! It worked! Thanks, it'll be useful

Comment: Hey there, I am here again. Ctrl + K worked but I'd like to know if it is also possible to highlight throughout the entire file the selected variable (as it is by default in Dymola). Right now, in Eclipse I am using the Modelica editor. I checked that this works with the generic text editor, but then, it doesn’t distinguish the basic Modelica words such as “parameter”, “redeclare function” or “for, if, else” etc.